# Rails - Conditional if syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, if-statement, syntax, conditional-formatting

I am starting with rails, and I can't write this on a rails syntax. Can I use the variable like this? How can I compare 2 variables with the true, false format?

```
 <% n = 0 %>
 <% @clas.each do |f| %>
    <% if f.clas_id != n %>
        <div>
            <h2> <%= f.clas_id%></h2>
        </div>
    <% else %>
      <% if f.clas_id = n %>
        <div class = "title">
            <h3><%= f.name%></h3>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>PA</th>
                    <th>Disim.</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= f.prec_id %></td>
                    <td><%= f.dis_id %></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <% else %>
            <% n = f.clas_id %><%= n %>
    <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: 1) I can't see `@clas` to be defined anywhere 2) You are using clas_id and clase_id - are those the same? 3) Look better at your conditions: there's  `if f.clas_id != n` and opposite one which can not consist of more conditions simple because there won't be any left!

Comment: 1) '@clas' is controller - '@clas = ACp.clas' who trade to a scope. 'scope :clas, lambda { order("a_cps.clas_id DESC").group("a_cps.clas_id")}'. 2) yes, It is the same.

Comment: `if f.clas_id = n` <- that looks suspicious. `=` is assignment, `==` is equality. Aren't you, by chance, confusing these two?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<% @clas.each do |f| %>
  <% if f.clas_id != n %>
    <div>
      <h2><%= f.clas_id %></h2>
    </div>
  <% elsif f.clas_id == n %>
    <div class = "title">
      <h3><%= f.name %></h3>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>PA</th>
          <th>Disim.</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><%= f.prec_id %></td>
          <td><%= f.dis_id %></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <% n = f.clase_id %><%= n %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Im not sure what your trying to do with `<% n = 0 %>`

You dont write else if statements like you have in Ruby you write:

```
<% elsif %>
```

Comment: Im trying to give a variable to account the _id, while the _id are the same, do the if, when change put title and change the variable to be the same again.

Comment: If you want to change the id permanently, you would need to apply this logic within the model

Comment: I only want to check whichi is the clas_id (foreing key) asigned to the row. to put berofe a title for the group

Comment: Solve. change to the elsif, and make two conditionals.